# Pygame no video

Tags: python, pygame

I am wondering if someone can help me with pygame(Python). I keep getting an error from my code:

```
bif ="bg.jpg"
mif = "mouse.png"
import pygame
import sys

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((682,415),0,32)
backround= pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c=pygame.image.load(mif).convert()
x, y =0,0
movex, movey =0,0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.tpye == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex =-1
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=+1
            elif event.key ==K_UP:
                movey=-1
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=+1
```

And the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Aidan\Desktop\Mygame.py", line 15, in <module>
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((682,415),0,32)
pygame.error: No available video device`
```

I have a Sony Vaio VGN-T1XP running on Windows XP.

Comment: Try `screen=pygame.display.set_mode((682,415))` perhaps it has a problem with the depth you are passing.

Comment: Is your desktop set to 32-bit color depth? Try 24 bit. Try reading the output of [display.Info](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.Info).

Comment: Depth? please explain im a noob at pygame

Comment: And i checked its 32 I Know You Can Edit

Comment: You can edit your comment instead of commenting twice (within 5 minutes of posting your comment.)

Comment: It runs well on my end, and i just tested it with 2 laptops. How do you run it (exact command, is that just windows cmd or powershell?), what is your python environment?

Comment: I use Idle Shell And thanks to all of my repliers who replied so quickly and with such good ideads

Comment: Ive also tried it in Python windows cmd and all of that. my computer is old and has low RAM (512mb) so i can't install anything major...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue with outdated hardware/software you got there. You can try submitting an issue with pygame, or try debugging pygame yourself to find out why but it's going to be complex. I really can't replicate it, even tried with my windows XP virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Also sounds like an issue with the depth to me... From the PyGame documentation:

"It is usually best to not pass the depth argument. It will default to the best and fastest color depth for the system. If your game requires a specific color format you can control the depth with this argument. Pygame will emulate an unavailable color depth which can be slow."

You find it here:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode

So the best solution would be to just leave flag and depth on default. I always used it that way round so far. From some older code of mine:

```
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
```

Try it this way round and let us know whether it worked or not. And have more fun with PyGame, I really start to love it :D If you need any more good tutorials, feel free to ask me :)